# responding to Done button UIKeyboard for A LOT of different UITextFields

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a UIView with a lot of UITextFields on it and I want to close the keyboard when the user hits the done button.  Setting a delegate on 20 different fields seems like overkill.  Is there a way to get notified when they hit the 'Done' button?

Comment: what do you mean by "Setting a delegate on 20 different fields seems like overkill"? Too much writing? If so you can connect them in xib. Or you can make a loop through all subviews of your view and check if it is a UITextField and, if so, set its delegate to self. It will only take a few lines of code

Comment: We get notification when the keyboard will show via NSNotification - you'd think there would be a mechanism in place for the done button is all I was hoping for

Comment: I just checked and I didn't find any notifications for pressing the "Done" button. I guess you will have to set the delegates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, If you want a callback from any UI element - you'll need to be it's delegate.